# Approximate values from point groupings

Tags: average, clustering

Say I am given a set of values: \begin{bmatrix}0.9&1.1&1&1.95&2&2.05&2.95&2.95&3.1&3\end{bmatrix}
Is there a way I can get the 'center' or 'average' values 1, 2, and 3 without splitting the data set up? Basically, is there a way to evaluate the entire set of numbers and get an output that says these numbers seem to exist around 1, 2, and 3? Even getting pointed in a general direction would be really helpful.